# Where is config.yml for FOSUserBundle configuration located in Flex?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, fosuserbundle

I am trying to include `FOSUserBundle` in my Symfony application. The [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) mentions an `app/config/config.yml` file, but there is none in my application. I think it's because I have a Flex structure.

Anyone knows where I should put the `fos_user` configuration in my app?

Comment: To whomever has modified the title of the question to include Symfony 4, in fact, I don't think it is related to Symfony's version, but to Flex only. I am on 3.4 since FOSUserBundle is not ready (i.e., tagged) for release 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config file should be `config/packages/fos_user.yaml` with the symfony flex structure.

The `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` recipe's [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/pull/210/files) is still not merged as of 2018-01-25.