# Unrecognized option "resource" under "fos_user"

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, fosuserbundle

I am integrating FOSUserBundle in my application and I am trying to run `php bin/console doctrine:migration:diff` after following the recommended set-up.

I am systematically getting a:

```
In ArrayNode.php line 319:

  Unrecognized option "resource" under "fos_user"
```

Yet, I have set the following in my `config/packages/routing.yaml`:

```
framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: ~

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

What am I doing wrong? I have `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0"` in my `composer.json` and ran `composer update`.

**Update**

My `fos_user.yaml` is:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\Admin\User
    from_email:
        address: no_reply@xxx.com
        sender_name: xxx
```

Comment: can you show config.yml ?

Comment: I don't have any, since I have a Flex structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445106/where-is-config-yml-for-fosuserbundle-configuration-located-in-symfony4-flex

Comment: Have you tried to put the route config into `config/routes.yaml` instead of `config/packages/routing.yaml`?

Comment: Aaaarrrgh... stupid me! If you create a solution, I'll approve it.

Comment: I think is because you din't enable your bundle in AppKernel with `new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),`

Comment: Hector: the bundle is enabled in `/config/bundles.php`. Dlondero's suggestion worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dlondero's suggestion fixed the issue, the `fos_user` configuration should be set in `config/routes.yaml`.

From [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html), routes are never automatically added in configuration.

Answer (score 6):

If I am not wrong, `config/packages/routing.yaml` file is not for routes, it is the config file for routing bundle, you can not put your routing configs to there. Instead, you should put them under `config/routes` folder, as `bundle_name.yml`.

Like this, eg. `config/routes/imagine.yml`:

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"
```

Answer (score 6):

move the :

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

into `config/routes.yaml` insted of `confing/packages/routing.yml`

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Symfony 4.3.2 skeleton

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

should be pasted in

```
config/routes/annotations.yaml
```

and

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

displays all the fos_user routes